# Accesing CMake-generated dynamic library with dlopen

Tags: c, cmake, dlopen

I want to compile a library as dynamic plugin (`MODULE`) and then acces it from executable using dlopen() function, but it keeps returning NULL.

I assume it can't find the library, so I probably miss sth in my CMakeLists.txt. Here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(find)

add_library(find MODULE ./src/find.c)
add_executable(foo ./src/foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Code of foo.c:

```
#include <stdlib>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void* lib = dlopen(find.so);

    /* code using the library with dlsym */

    dlclose(lib);
    return 0;
}
```

I've searched through the docs and other questions, but nothing helped me. I'm CMake novice, so it's possible I simply didn't understand proper sources - if it is so, I kindly ask if someone could put it straightforward: how to properly compile and access `MODULE` library with CMake?

Comment: "I assume it can't find the library" - Have you checked whether the library is in the same directory where you have your executable?

Comment: I can't see the .so files anywhere around after compilation, nor did I succed in making CMake  place them where I want. It workes though with other .so (`SHARED`) version of linking, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a library in a POSIX environment, the default name will have a `lib` prefix. This is explained in the [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) documentation.

So for the library target `find`, the linked file will be named `libfind.so`, which is the filename you need to pass to `dlopen`.

And of course, the working directory of the executable (basically the directory where you run the program from) must be where the library is. Or you need to include the path to the library.

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly a good point. Sadly, changing the name didn't yet solve the issue.

Comment: @tyrrr Try printing the result of [`dlerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlerror.3.html) immediately once `dlopen` fails (as mentioned in the [`dlopen` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)).

Comment: @tyrrr And to find out where CMake placed the file, after you run `make` then run `find . -name libfind.so`. Assuming there were no errors of course.

Comment: It says: "libfind.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @tyrrr Then you need to give the path to the library. `dlopen` uses the normal path and working directory rules. Unlike Windows, `dlopen` does not look in the same directory as the executable program. This is mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I've tried finding it like that, but it returns nothing; what makes it even stranger is that there is in fact another .so library compiled using the same cmake, linked as shared - it works fine, but I can't find it either.

Comment: Thank you guys, it workes now. Little shame to say, but I missed cmake placing the `.so` files in another directory, level above "build" which I've sticked to. Anyway, specifying path to file correctly obviously did the job. What's maybe worth mentioning - adding the lib prefix seems to apply to `MODULE' too.